# Using BitcoinDevKit as a pallet dependency

Tags: pallet, wasm

When I add [BitcoinDevKit](https://docs.rs/bdk/latest/bdk/index.html) as a dependency to the `pallet-template`, I get compilation errors within the `socks` crate that I don't get when compiling BDK standalone. It seems that BDK supports compilation to `WASM`, but I am not sure.

Is it possible to use `BDK functionality` within a pallet? How can I satisfy these compilation errors?

```
  error[E0599]: no method named `writev` found for struct `UdpSocket` in the current scope
     --> /home/max/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socks-0.3.4/src/v5.rs:391:21
      |
  391 |         self.socket.writev([&header[..len + 3], buf])
      |                     ^^^^^^ method not found in `UdpSocket`
      |
      = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
  note: `WritevExt` defines an item `writev`, perhaps you need to implement it
     --> /home/max/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socks-0.3.4/src/writev.rs:4:1
      |
  4   | pub trait WritevExt {
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `bdk` so can't provide specific info regarding it. Only libraries that allow compiling under `no_std` are supported to be used in the runtime. The fact that this is trying to compile sockets clearly shows that this is not the case (you can't do system calls from the runtime).

Here's an issue on their repo for this: https://github.com/bitcoindevkit/bdk/issues/205

Comment: Makes sense. I was thinking something like this was the case. I believe that I can create a new off-chain service separate from the node and then call that service from the OCW to do the BDK work.